# Only One Trait Among Many Returns BadMethodCallException When I Call A Method In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I'm probably missing something stupid here because the issue doesn't make sense at all.

I have VerifyController, which calls one of the verify methods based on the passed model name.

```
public function update(Request $request, $model)
{
    $task = "verify" . ucfirst($model);
    return $this->{$task}($request->all());
}
```

In my current use case, this method calls `verifyPost()` method which is stored in a trait named Posts.

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Posts
{
    public function verifyPost($items)
    {
        $verifiedItems = [];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $item['verified'] = array_merge(
                $this->checkIfListCompatible($item),
                $this->checkIfVideosExist($item),
                $this->checkIfImagesExist($item)
            );
            $verifiedItems[] = $item;
        }
        return $verifiedItems;
    }
}
```

verifyPost() calls 3 methods and they are in different traits:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Lists
{
    public function checkIfListCompatible($item)
    {
       return [
           'lists' => true
       ];
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Images
{
    public function checkIfImagesExist($item)
    {
       return [
           'images' => true
       ];
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Videos
{
    public function checkIfVideosExist($item)
    {
       return [
           'videos' => true
       ];
    }
}
```

Since all 4 traits are in the same namespace, I didn't add any "use" statement to any one of them (and I cannot add them because they create different errors due to mutual using), but somehow only `checkIfListCompatible()` returns `BadMethodCallException (checkIfListCompatible does not exist)`, while the other two work well.

More interestingly, Lists trait has some other methods that can be found by the other traits including Posts. So Posts can use one method from Lists trait and cannot the other. I'm sure there is no typo and the method is public.

So please let me know what I'm missing here.

BTW, I've already clear the cache and everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `VerifyController` use all the traits?

Comment: I knew I was missing something stupid. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: All good. Sometimes the simplest things are the last thing you think of :)